# XSLT mapping to add missing child tags in the same sequence

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have the below input xml where some mandatory xml tags are missing like <email_template_id>
which needs to be reproduced in the output in the same sequence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp stat="ok" version="1.0">
<result>
<total_results>700</total_results>
<emailClick>
<id>1</id>
<url>https://www.google.com</url>
<email_template_id>12</email_template_id>
<created_at>2023-02-14 00:00:10</created_at>
</emailClick>
<emailClick>
<id>2</id>
<url>https://www.hello.com</url>
<created_at>2023-02-14 00:00:10</created_at>
</emailClick>
</result>
</rsp>
```

and need the below output

```
<emailClick>
<id>1</id>
<url>https://www.google.com</url>
<email_template_id>12</email_template_id>
<created_at>2023-02-14 00:00:10</created_at>
</emailClick>
<emailClick>
<id>2</id>
<url>https://www.hello.com</url>
<email_template_id/>
<created_at>2023-02-14 00:00:10</created_at>
</emailClick>
```

I am using below xslt to achieve this output

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent ="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="rsp/result/emailClick">
<emailClick>
<id><xsl:value-of select="id" /></id>
<url><xsl:value-of select="url" /></url>
<email_template_id><xsl:value-of select="email_template_id"/></email_template_id>
<created_at><xsl:value-of select="created_at"/></created_at>
</emailClick>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there any better  way to achieve this , any guidance would be highly appreciated

Comment: Can all the four child elements shown (`id`, `url`, `email_template_id`, `created_at`) be missing and need to be explicitly created?

Comment: No martin it is not all child elements , few are mandatory like email_template_id,created_at, I need a more generic way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet avoids any mention of element names inside the `xsl:for-each` and instead reads the mandatory element names from the `<so:emailClick>` element and processes them generically:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:so="https://stackoverflow.com">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <so:emailClick>
    <id />
    <url />
    <email_template_id />
    <created_at />
  </so:emailClick>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="rsp/result/emailClick">
      <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/so:*[local-name()=name(current())]/*">
          <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$this/*[name()=name(current())]" />
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is that what you meant by "a generic way of doing this"?

(XSLT 1.0)

Comment: What is the advantage of the added complexity??

Comment: The author asked for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a push programming approach.  Which means it pushes the child nodes using apply-templates.  It also uses a mode.  So the nodes being output are pushed to an identity template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent ="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="emailClick">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="output"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="id">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="id" mode="output"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="id"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="url">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="url" mode="output"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="url"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="email_template_id">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="email_template_id" mode="output"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="email_template_id"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="created_at">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="created_at" mode="output"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="created_at"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Identity. -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="output">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="output"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the advantage of the added complexity??

Comment: I see your point.  The reason I have shown this is because it's push programming which is what XSLT is designed to do.  And the submitter asked for a better way to achieve this.  One advantage of this approach is that it will still work if the XML changes, as long as the emailClick nodes stay the same.  If there is no chance of the XML changing then please ignore.  But, when the XML hierarchy is a moving target, this is useful.